# Show that any metrizable space $X$ is regular

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

This is a quick follow up to another question [Show that any metrizable space $X$ is Hausdorff](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862598/show-that-any-metrizable-space-x-is-hausdorff)

> Recall, a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is *regular* if we can separate any
>   point  $x$ from closed set $C$ using disjoint open sets $U,V \in
>  \mathcal{T}$.

**Show that any metrizable space is regular**

---

**Proof attempt:**

- Let $x \in X\backslash C$ be a point, and $C \subset X$ any closed
  set.
- Since $X$ is metrizable, the metric $d$ generating topology on
  $X$ induces a point-to-set distance $d(x,C) = \inf\{d(x,c)| c \in C\}$
- It is easy to see that $d(x,C) > 0, \thinspace \forall x \in X \backslash C$.
- Let $r = d(x,C)$, then $B_r(x)$ is an open set containing $x$
  disjoint from $C$

  ...Now construct an open set that contains $C$ disjoint from $x$ and
  we are done...

How do I construct such a set...

**Idea**:

> Take $y \in \partial C$, and $B_{\epsilon_y}(y)$ such that 
>   $B_{\epsilon_y}(y) \cap B_{r}(x) = \varnothing, \forall \epsilon_y>0$. Then $\bigcup_{y \in \partial C} B_{\epsilon_y}(y) \cup C$ is an open set (hmm union of open with closed = open?) containing $C$
>   disjoint from $x$.

Is there a more satisfying  way to produce this open set than taking these arbitrary lengthed balls and unioning them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $r=d(x,C)$, I think that $U=B_{r/2}(x)$ and $V=\bigcup_{y\in C}B_{r/2}(y)$ should work.

Comment: Meow! Meow! Bark! Bark!

Comment: I meant nothing by that. I will rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

It’s certainly not hard to show that $d(x,C)>0$ if $C$ is closed and $x\notin C$, but this *is* something that requires proof. As for the rest, just take any positive $r\le\frac12d(x,C)$ and use $B_d(x,r)$ and

$$\bigcup_{y\in C}B_d(y,r)\;.$$

It also takes a little work to show that $\bigcup_{y\in\operatorname{bdry}C}B_d(y,\epsilon_y)\cup C$ is open, and this doesn’t really help you anyway: the set doesn’t contain $x$, but it certainly need not be disjoint from $B_d(x,r)$.

Comment: can you just take $X\backslash \bar{B}_{d}(x,r)$ as an open set containing $C$ disjoint from $x$?

Comment: @n1000: Only if $r<d(x,C)$; if $r=d(x,C)$, $\operatorname{cl}B_d(x,r)$ may intersect $C$.