# Yes/ No Is $\mathbb{Q}$ Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

Is  $\mathbb{Q}$ Hausdorff ?Yes/ No

My attempt : I think yes

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|a-b|=\epsilon > 0$ and $a >b$

Take $A= ( a- \frac{\epsilon}{3} , a + \frac{\epsilon}{3})$ and $B= ( b- \frac{\epsilon}{3} , b + \frac{\epsilon}{3})$

$\implies A \cap B= \emptyset$

Therefore , $\mathbb{Q}$ is Hausdorff

Comment: Yes that's OK. Minor quibbles: you don't use $a > b$. Maybe prove fully that $A \cap B=\emptyset$? This works in any metric space, use the triangle inequality..

Comment: @ArcticChar i think my question is different

Comment: I agree, but what about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1862598/446262)?

Comment: yes sir @JoséCarlosSantos I think this question  is almost similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right, but there is a part that hasn't been prooved.

If $x\in A\cap B$, then $3\epsilon=|a-b|\le|a-x|+|x-b|<2\epsilon$, so this is contradiction. $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

In fact, there exists well-defined metric on $\mathbb Q$ ($d(p,q)=|p-q|$), so $\mathbb Q$ is Hausdorff space.

Comment: I'm not getting  How you got $|a-b|= 3\epsilon?$  I think $|a-b|= \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Set $c:=\frac{a+b}{2}$. Then $A:=\{x \in \mathbb{Q} : x <c \}$ and $B:=\{x \in \mathbb{Q} : x >c \}$ are open disjoint sets containig $a$ and $b$ respectively